# Time difference between dateTime fields SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, datediff, datepart

I have two datetime fields and I need to show the difference between them. I've used this expression to calculate it:

```
=DateDiff("n", Fields!hra_atncion.Value, Fields!fcha_incio.Value)
```

The result column should be on **HH:mm**, but the result is a Long expression type. Something like **428011156**

Any answer will be apreciated!

**UPDATE 21/11/2013**

How I obtain the time difference in minutes between **12-11-2013 20:00** and **14-11-2013 08:00** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you should try this expression:

```
=Datediff("h",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) & ":" & Datediff("n",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) mod 60
```

Comment: I was typing up a similar answer. The one improvement I suggest is to add .ToString("00") to the second half to force two digits all the time: `=Datediff("h",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) & ":" & (Datediff("n",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value) mod 60).ToString("00")`