# Expression to find total time in minutes not working when amended to include DateDiff

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, datediff

I have 2 tablix in my report.  I need to find the total time in hours and minutes ignoring any day counts. In the appointments tablix  I am using expression

```
=FLOOR(Sum(Fields!actualdurationminutes.Value) / 60) & ":" & RIGHT("0" & (Sum(Fields!actualdurationminutes.Value) 
MOD 60), 2)
```

--acutaldurationminutes is a whole number field automatically populated by code behind the field calculating from the start and end times.

I want to do the same in the events tablix but the column I need to total is made up of the time difference between 2 datetime values instead of a single value.  I tried to add  DATEDIFF into the expression above to get a single time value but it is giving an error:

`=FLOOR(Sum(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute,Fields!ccx_startdate.Value,Fields!ccx_enddate.Value))/60)&":"& RIGHT("0"&(Sum(DATEDIFF(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!ccx_startdate.Value,Fields!ccx_enddate.Value))MOD 60),2)`

I have spent many hours trying to find a solution to this and used this to help with the DateDiff part of the expression:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084113/time-difference-between-datetime-fields-ssrs - help to find how to use datediff in expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20084113/time-difference-between-datetime-fields-ssrs%20-%20help%20to%20find%20how%20to%20use%20datediff%20in%20expression) 
however there still seems to be something not quite right.   I am getting error 'Argument not specified for parameter 'Length' of 'Public function RIGHT(str as String, Length as Integer)AS STRING'

When I have got this right I will then need to add together the answer from both expressions to get the total time per customer in hh:mm

I would be grateful for any help on this.  I am learner level so I apologize if I have been too detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following code:

=(FLOOR(Sum(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!ccx_startdate.Value, Fields!ccx_enddate.Value))/60)) &":"& FLOOR(Sum(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute,Fields!ccx_startdate.Value,Fields!ccx_enddate.Value)))-((FLOOR(Sum(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!ccx_startdate.Value, Fields!ccx_enddate.Value))/60))*60)

Comment: Marked as correct answer, however could you tell me what I need to add to get 7:0 to read as 07:00 (but I don't want 25 hours to read as 1:01:00 - just as the number of hours 25:00) - is that just formatting in the tablix cell or do I need to add something to the expression?

Comment: Using the same original code but adding in format conditions: please try: =Format((FLOOR(Sum(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!ccx_startdate.Value, Fields!ccx_enddate.Value))/60)),"00") &":"& Format(FLOOR(Sum(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute,Fields!ccx_startdate.Value,Fields!ccx_enddate.Value)))-((FLOOR(Sum(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Fields!ccx_startdate.Value, Fields!ccx_enddate.Value))/60))*60),"00")

Comment: note that if the number of hours exceeds 99hrs, only the first two numbers are displayed

Comment: So, the formatting is wrapped around the existing expression.  This works beautifully and the clarification was very useful.